# How do I extract text after some text is matched that is itself a regex after few tags in regex in python

Tags: python, regex

This is my text

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 pull-right jd_rol_section">
<div class="heading">Walk-in Details:</div>
<div class=""><span><b>Venue Details: </b></span><span>Shall be available on successful application.</span><br/><span><b>City: </b></span><span>Bengaluru / Bangalore</span><br/><span><b>Date: </b></span><span>27/11/2018 To 27/11/2018</span><br/>
<span><b>Timings: </b></span><span>10:00 AM to 5:00 PM</span><br/></div> 
<div class="heading">Industry</div><span><a href="http://...." target="_blank" title="IT/ Computers - Software Jobs">IT/ Computers - Software</a></span> <div class="heading">Function</div><span><a href="http://...." target="_blank" title="IT Jobs">IT</a></span> <div class="heading">Role</div>
<span><a href="http://...." target="_blank" title="Graphic Designer/ Animator Jobs">Graphic Designer/ Animator</a><br/></span> <div class="heading">Education</div>
<span><a href="http://....">Diploma</a><br/></span> <!--<div class="heading">Summary</div>
                       <span style="word-wrap: break-word;"> 1-2 year of Work experience
Proven graphic designing experience.
Possession of creative flair, versatility, conceptual/visual ability and originality.
Demonstrable graphic design skills with a strong portfolio.
Ability to interact, communicate and present ideas.
Up to date with industry leading software and technologies (&#8203;In Design, Illustrator, CorelDRAW, Photoshop&#8203; etc In Particular)
Highly proficient in all design aspects.
Professionalism regarding time, costs and deadline
Should have basic knowledge of sketching, perspective and sketching characters (In Particular)</span>-->
<div class="heading">Posted On</div><span> 23rd Nov 2018</span> </div>
```

on the 5th line you can see "Industry". I want to extract the text written outside any tag just after that. here which is "IT/ Computers - Software" on the sixth line. There are many such text docs. I want an efficient way to loop through all the documents using regex. Consider the structure of all docs to be same.

I have tried

```
x = re.search('Industry\<\/div\>\<span\>?*\<\/span\>', chunk_data)
```

which did not work. Can you also tell me the reason.

Comment: HTML should be parsed with an HTML parser and regex is meant to find matches in the plain text. Please share your BS code.

Comment: that is ok I know but please tell me how do i extract using regex. Its a plain text I have provided the document. please don't downvote my post.

Comment: Remove that useless image – what do you think we could use it for? – and add enough of your sample text into the question itself to reproduce your problem.

Comment: the text contained tags and backslash characters, when I copied into the text area. The tag converted to HTML tag and was not visible. Be nice be respectful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to extract `a` tag?

```
x = re.search(r'Industry.*?(<a.*?</a>)', chunk_data)
# or
#x = re.search(r'Industry</div><span>(.*?)</span>', chunk_data)

print(x.group(1))
```